# How to invoke the appium server via python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, shell, appium

I am trying to start an appium server via a call to a python function at the start of my script.

I found the line I used to type into the windows command prompt was:
`appium --base-path /wd/hub --default-capabilities "{\"app\": \"myapp.app\"}"`

This worked fine.

Therefore, I tried the following in python:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("""start appium --base-path /wd/hub --default-capabilities "{\"app\": \"myapp.app\"}"
""",shell=True)
```

This gives the following error:
`C:\Users\jainv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js: error: argument -dc/--default-capabilities: invalid parseDefaultCaps value: '{app: myapp.app}'`

It appears to be removing the "" around the capabilities dict and replacing them with single quotes instead. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
# --base-path has to give which is used to slove https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/15813
# [HTTP] no route found for /wd/hub/session
from appium.webdriver.appium_service import AppiumService
appium_service = AppiumService()
appium_service.start(args=["--base-path", "/wd/hub"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Long keys did not work for me. What worked for me is

```
appium_service.start(args=['-pa', '/wd/hub'])
```